# I2C ADC data read and write

Tags: i2c

I have i2c ADC MAX11646(to detect the temperature using LM35), trying to interface with Raspberry Pi through I2C.
`i2cdetect -y 1` shows the connected i2c devices.

Now I cannot read the ADC values. I've use `i2cset -y 1 0x36 0x21` to set the channel 1 and tried `i2cget -y 1 0x36` to read the data.

its always returns `oxfc` . The channel 2 output is always `oxff`

How can I get the proper result. Any help is appreciated .

Comment: The datasheet for the device will specify the commands you send, the data returned, and how to interpret the data.

Comment: The datasheet doesn't provide any register address to access the ADC output. So I think we just need to access it using the device i2c address. But that's not working in my case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @joan says, the [datasheet](https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/280/MAX11647-pdf.php) will help you ...

> ...The result is transmitted in 2 bytes; first 6 bits of the first byte
>   are high, then MSB through LSB are consecutively clocked out.

So, the first 6 bits are high, hence the values you'll see in the first byte can only be 0xFC to 0xFF.

You need to read 2 bytes instead of 1. I don't think `i2cget` can do that (without specifying the register address). You **might** have some luck with `i2cdump`.

**Maybe**:
`i2cdump -y 1 0x36 w`

Comment: `i2cdump` showed me a lot of data on the screen. What is it actually? Is it the register output?

How really can I get the 10 bit output ?

Comment: really sorry to ask u a lot, I'm a newbie and dont have much knowledge in this.

Comment: It is just a dump of values requested from the device (some may be invalid / non existant).  I'd be interested in the first value - that **might** contain your reading.  However, to get the actual 10bit output you really need to do some coding - python, c, whatever, as long as it provides access to i2c

Comment: Oh thankyou for the prompt reply. 

What does the top row actually mean at the output of `i2cdump`

Comment: @Sam `man i2cdump`